# Outputting Unicode character in Console window in C#

Tags: unicode, console

My application generate Persian text and show it in console window as unknown code!
How can I have Unicode text in my application output in console?
I used to below code but it doesn't work proper!

```
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Answer (score 7):

You should set your *output* encoding if you want *output* to appear correctly:

```
public class Test {
    static void Main() {
        System.Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        System.Console.WriteLine("پارسی");
    }
}
```

works for me (and yes, even though the Windows console uses UTF-16 you have to set UTF-8; I have no idea why).

```
C:\>test.exe
پارسی
```

Note that the console may show `?????` in which case you need to set the console font to a TrueType font (e.g. Consolas or Lucida Console), otherwise the console tries converting everything into the OEM character set and characters that cannot be converted become question marks. After that the console shows still no Persian because there is no complex script rendering support, but you can copy/paste it just fine.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Windows uses UCS-2 internally. Have you tried converting your text into this encoding?

Comment: Windows hasn't used UCS-2 for over a decade now.